# How can I get in SIPML5 the remote display name?

Tags: webrtc, sip, sipml5

I have an issue getting the remote display name with the sipML5 library. When I register the user, I set in the stack object the display_name.

```
display_name: local_username
```

After when I make the call I can see in my SIPml.Session.Call object the display_name.

```
SIPml.Session.Call.o_session.o_uri_from.s_display_name = 'local_username';
```

In the remote peer, when I get that call invitation with 'i_new_call' event, the field is empty

```
SIPml.Session.Call.o_session.o_uri_from.s_display_name = null;
```

How can I get the display name in the remote end? or is there another way to get that variable name

Answer (score 0):

I get the display name, it was in another object type stored

```
SIPml.Stack.Event.o_event.o_message.o_hdr_From.s_display_name
```